# How to show 0 instead of NULL while fetching data my sql table

Tags: mysql, sql, null

I am fetching data from mysql table it works fine, but it shows `NULL` for `Status` in two fields. I want instead of `NULL` show `0`.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT ml.GroupID, ml.GroupTitle, ml.GroupDescription, ml.GroupCreatedDateTime, ml.GroupOwnerUserID, ml.ApprovalNeeded, ml.GroupStatus, ml.OrganizationCode, cat.Status
FROM GroupsMaster AS ml
LEFT JOIN UserGroupsMapping cat ON cat.GroupID = ml.GroupID
WHERE ml.OrganizationCode = ?
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use the [COALESCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) operator

```
   COALESCE(cat.Status, 0)


SELECT 
 ml.GroupID, 
 ml.GroupTitle, 
 ml.GroupDescription, 
 ml.GroupCreatedDateTime, 
 ml.GroupOwnerUserID, 
 ml.ApprovalNeeded, 
 ml.GroupStatus, 
 ml.OrganizationCode, 
 COALESCE(cat.Status, 0) as Status 
FROM GroupsMaster AS ml 
LEFT JOIN UserGroupsMapping cat ON cat.GroupID = ml.GroupID 
WHERE ml.OrganizationCode = 'ibm'
```

Comment: SELECT ml.GroupID, ml.GroupTitle, ml.GroupDescription, ml.GroupCreatedDateTime, ml.GroupOwnerUserID, ml.ApprovalNeeded, ml.GroupStatus, ml.OrganizationCode, cat.Status COALESCE(cat.Status, 0)
   FROM GroupsMaster AS ml
   LEFT JOIN UserGroupsMapping cat ON cat.GroupID = ml.GroupID
   WHERE ml.OrganizationCode =  'ibm'

Comment: please see my query as you are saying to use it does not work

Comment: @user2240329 you still have a cat.Status lost in your code (and / or a missing comma). See my edited answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try [ifnull()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) function.
like belowing:

select **ifnull**(cat.status,0) as status
FROM GroupsMaster AS ml
LEFT JOIN UserGroupsMapping cat ON cat.GroupID = ml.GroupID
WHERE ml.OrganizationCode =  '$organizationCode'");

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
SELECT 
 ml.GroupID, 
 ml.GroupTitle, 
 ml.GroupDescription, 
 ml.GroupCreatedDateTime, 
 ml.GroupOwnerUserID, 
 ml.ApprovalNeeded, 
 ml.GroupStatus, 
 ml.OrganizationCode, 
 COALESCE(cat.Status, 0) as Status 
FROM GroupsMaster AS ml 
LEFT JOIN UserGroupsMapping cat ON cat.GroupID = ml.GroupID 
and ml.OrganizationCode = 'ibm'
```